# Flutter Applications Not Showing In Google Play Store On Emulator

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I have published several applications on the Google Play Store and I wanted to download one of them using an emulator.

What I noticed was, that when I look at the applications under my name through the Google Play Store on an emulated device, ***all Flutter applications are missing***.

[image: Play Store Screenshot Emulator]

When I do the same thing in a browser on a computer, I do see all my applications (notice how Pill shows up):

[image: Play Store Screenshot Browser]

> Clarification: Pill is not the only Flutter application I have
> published and the screenshot doesn't show the entire application
> catalog)

I tried looking online for anything that would explain this, since even on my computer, I cannot download the applications, ***but they are showing up***.

What could be causing this?

---

**EDIT**

When copying the direct Google Play link and pasting it in Chrome on the emulator, it opens Google Play and allows me to download and install the application.

[image: Screenshot]

When doing the same thing inside Google Play on the device, the link shows me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your application would have bot been released in all countries. In web it might show all applications but in a device it will display based on countries that the app is available to check the same please follow these steps

Go to Play Console.

Select an app.
Select Release > Production > Countries/regions.

Update your app's country selection.

Submit your app update.

Comment: My application is published to all countries. When using a physical mobile device, I see my Flutter applications.

Comment: Try opening the direct url of the app in the simulator. Either the device or the country must not be supported

Comment: How can it not be supported if it is published to all countries?

Comment: Device comparability also plays a role,sdk version, country may be different. Please try the direct link once and it will open the app with the reason below saying like unavailable in your country or unsupported device etc

Comment: Kaushik Chandru - Tried what you suggested by copying the direct link and pasting it in Chrome. It opens Google Play with the application and says I can install. it. There is no country/device issues.

Comment: You are checking this in browser again i think. Please paste the url in Google Play in simulator. In browser it will work.

Comment: Kaushik Chandru - I did that as well and got nothing.

Comment: From my mobile I am able to see the pill app and 5 others. Open any of the apps shown in list and click on your developer account and see if you are getting the pill app in the list

Comment: Kaushik Chandru - That is literally what I describe in my question.

Comment: Which simulator are you using

Answer (score 0):

The Play Store enabled emulator images are x86 images so they can be executed faster on an Intel/AMD CPU. Physical smartphones at the moment all use ARM CPUs (armv8a 64 bit to be precise).

If an app uses CPU specific native libraries it needs to include one version them for each CPU architecture it plans to support. Therefore if the app you want to install in the emulator only has native libraries for ARM then it can not be executed on an x86 emulator and thus will not be shown in Play Store.

Comment: I thought about this as well, but my applications do not have any CPU specific libraries).